# Python exercise generate an array with abs and argmin

Tags: python

> Generate a 10 x 3 array of random numbers in [0,1].
>
> For each row, pick the number closest to 0.5.
>
> Use `abs` and `argmin` to find the column j closest for each row

I don't understand the solution, could you please help me out?

#### Solution

```
x1 = np.random.random([10,3])
print(x1)

c05 = [a[np.abs(a-0.5).argmin()] for a in x1]
print(c05)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at first, we create a 10x3 array using 

`x1 = np.random.random([10,3])`

Then we want to iterate rows one by one to pick the number closet to 0.5.
We just need to find which element in current row minusing 0.5 is the smallest(absolute value). And to find the smallest element we can use [argmin()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) function, which returns the `indices of the minimum values along an axis`.

We can simply write:

```
result = []
for row in x:
    distance = np.abs(row-0.5)
    smallest_index = distance.argmin()
    result.append(row[smallest_index])
```

Writing the above code in `list comprehension` form, we get your solution.

Comment: But if it gives us the indices of the minimum values along an axis, why is it that if I use np.argmin(x1) do I get just one scalar, instead of 10 scalars?

Comment: @PedroPinheiro. Good question. Try read the `argmin()` docs again and you'll find the detailed explanation to the parameter `axis` is `  axis : int, optional . By default, the index is into the flattened array, otherwise along the specified axis.` So when you use `np.argmin(x1)`, it flattens the  `x1` into 1-d array first and then to find the min index.

Comment: Okay, that's the explanation I needed! So it is better if we don't use the default because that way we can use it without a for cycle!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the explanation:

```
#this just creates an array 10x3
x1 = np.random.random([10,3])

#prints the array
print(x1)
```

now the next bit is where the actual logic happens. Let's break it down:

first we measure the difference between the row data point and 0.5 which is the point we want to find the value closest to. And then we take absolute value of that, as we don't care if the difference is negative or positive.

```
np.abs(a-0.5)
```

Then after such transformation of the row we find the index on which this value is minimal.

```
np.abs(a-0.5).argmin()
```

After which we just extract the value of this index

```
a[np.abs(a-0.5).argmin()]
```

Doing this for every row results in the list comprehension as you have written :

```
[a[np.abs(a-0.5).argmin()] for a in x1]
```

Then we print the result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, I understand just until the point where you do the for cycle. How do you know if it is going along the arrows?